# I have an array of URLs that need to be passed into anchor tags

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

Using this to pass out an array of rgb values and create anchor tags

```
$.each(color, function(index, value){
    $('body').append($('<a class="color">').css({
        height: '30px',
        width: '30px',
        'background-color': value
    })
);
});
```

And then attempting to use this code to pass an array of URL's into those anchor tags

```
$.each(colorname, function(index, value){
    $('.color').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', value);
    });
});
```

Sample Arrays:

```
var color = [];
color[ 0 ] = 'RGB(233,232,217)';
color[ 1 ] = 'RGB(227,222,202)';
color[ 2 ] = 'RGB(218,210,186)';
color[ 3 ] = 'RGB(208,189,150)';
color[ 4 ] = 'RGB(213,208,194)';


var colorname = [];
colorname[ 0 ] = '/url1/';
colorname[ 1 ] = '/url2/';
colorname[ 2 ] = '/url3/';
colorname[ 3 ] = '/url4/';
colorname[ 4 ] = '/url5/';
```

It seems to get all of the URLs, but it appends the last item in the array colorname to all anchor tags.

Comment: ID's **must** be unique!

Comment: @tymeJV I think it's best if we just ignore this ever happened.

Comment: @Richard: jQuery sort of does that for you -- actually, it doesn't add markup to the page at all, it parses the HTML, fashions an HTMLAnchorElement from the tag, and then adds it to the DOM. No need to close the tag here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/L3qrq/

**JS:-**

```
var color = [];
color[ 0 ] = 'RGB(233,232,217)';
color[ 1 ] = 'RGB(227,222,202)';
color[ 2 ] = 'RGB(218,210,186)';
color[ 3 ] = 'RGB(208,189,150)';
color[ 4 ] = 'RGB(213,208,194)';


var colorname = [];
colorname[ 0 ] = '/url1/';
colorname[ 1 ] = '/url2/';
colorname[ 2 ] = '/url3/';
colorname[ 3 ] = '/url4/';
colorname[ 4 ] = '/url5/';

$.each(color, function (index, value) {
    var anchor=$('<a class="color">').css({
        height: '30px',
        width: '30px',
            'background-color': value
    }).attr("href",colorname[index]);
    $('body').append(anchor);
});
```

Comment: Success. Thanks for the help. Could you explain this or possibly provide me a link to some documentation for this? Thanks!

Comment: Being late to the party I would've taken the object oriented way of doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/RVEYZ/ instead of mucking about with indexes here and there.

Answer (score 0):

its make since, you run through you array of colorname's and set all `.color` to same value.

try this instead

```
 $('.color').each(function(index){
        $(this).attr('href', colorname[index]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions:

1. Segregation of duties -- you are mixing some constant CSS with DOM styling. I would move what you can out of the JavaScript:

   ```
   /* in a .css file somewhere... */
   .color {
       display: block;
       width: 30px;
       height: 30px;
       float: left;
   }
   ```
2. Parallel arrays are always a bad idea. If you have two or more arrays where the items at each index belong together, use an array of JS objects instead, with meaningful property names:

   ```
   var colors = [
       {
           rgb: 'RGB(233,232,217)',
           url: '/url1/'
       },
       {
           rgb: 'RGB(227,222,202)',
           url: '/url2/'
       },
       {
           rgb: 'RGB(218,210,186)',
           url: '/url3/'
       },
       {
           rgb: 'RGB(208,189,150)',
           url: '/url4/'
       },
       {
           rgb: 'RGB(213,208,194)',
           url: '/url5/'
       },
   ];
   ```
3. Keep your jQuery/JS simple. With the above two modifications, your JS code can be reduced to:

   ```
   $.each(colors, function () {
        $('<a class="color">')
           .css('background-color', this.rgb)
           .attr("href", this.url)
           .appendTo('body');
   });
   ```

   The code is very concise and its intent is now very clear. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jjTUz/2/)